# Can I assign a variable and test it at the same time using DRY principles in PHP?

Tags: php, dry

There are plenty of ways to do this. My question isn't "how do I test variables and assign variables". The question is how can I do this with the least amount of code possible and not repeat certain text.

It's common to need to read, validate and assign variables from GET or POST, I'm trying to find the most concise way to do it.

When I need a GET variable, I typically test it with both ISSET and EMPTY. Then I might do a further validation on the data type, and then finally assign it to a working variable. Like this for example:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {
    if (is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
        $var = $_GET['id'];
        // code
    }
}
```

I'm leaving out the various "else" conditions but you get the idea. The most obvious annoyance here is having to type `$_GET['id']` 4 times. Another one is having to do all my code within a 2-level if block.

My question is, can I do all the tests and validations and assignments in a more DRY way? Something like this pseudocode:

```
if ($var = isset(!empty(is_numeric($_GET['id']))) {
    // $var is now equal to $_GET['id'];
} else {
    // failed all tests, $var is equal to false;
}
```

Assuming that the GET passes the three tests, $var would be assigned the actual value of the GET, rather than true/false.

Yes I can do this and NOT be DRY. Yes I can do this with a custom function. I'm just wondering if I can wrap it all up this way or not, in a small, concise, DRY, single statement. I've been playing with tertiary statements but still not perfect and DRY.

Comment: FYI: `!empty` “includes” `isset`.

Comment: You should look into http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Comment: @Cbroe I've always been told to use both isset() and empty() on form validation due to some possible error conditions, i.e. checkboxes perhaps. Is this advice outdated? Since both functions test slightly different, you would have to use both to cover all cases.

Comment: You can safely use `!empty` only in this case i.e. it doesn't throw any errors in case variable, key or property doesn't exist same as `isset`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing with ternary operator like the following:

```
$var = empty($var) ? $default : $var;
```

Answer (score -1):

What about:

$getVar = empty($_GET['var'])?null : $_GET['var'];
$var = (!is_null($getVar) && is_numeric($getVar))? $getVar : false;

DRYest I can get it. 
(Sorry about the lack of formatting- am typing from a phone)